# update checkboxes after submit

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I am currently running into an issue, where I have this form consisting of checkboxes. I get the values of user preferences for the checkboxes from a database. Everything works great, and does what is supposed to do, however after I change and check some boxes and then hit the submit button, it will still show the old values to the form again. If I click again in the page again it will show the new values.

The code is shown below with comments.

```
<form action="myprofile.php" method="post">
<?php $usr_cats=array();
$qry_usrcat="SELECT category_id_fk 
             FROM user_categories 
             WHERE user_id_fk='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_usrcat);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $usr_cats[] = $row[0]; // getting user categories from db stored in array
}

$query_allcats="SELECT category_id,category_name, portal_name 
                FROM categories
                INNER JOIN portals on categories.portal_id=portals.portal_id
                ORDER BY category_id;";  // select all category queries
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query_allcats);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['portal_name'] . "<input "; //print categories
    if(in_array($row['category_id'], $usr_cats)){ // if in array from db, check the checkbox
        echo "checked ";
     }
    echo "type='checkbox' name='categories[]' value='";
    echo $row['category_id']."'> ". $row['category_name']."</br>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 <?php
$qry_del_usrcats="DELETE FROM user_categories
                WHERE user_id_fk='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';"; //delete all query
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['categories'])){
        $cats= $_POST['categories'];
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_del_usrcats); //delete all
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($cats); $x++) {
            $qry_add_usrcats="INSERT INTO `user_categories` (`user_id_fk`, `category_id_fk`) 
                     VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$cats[$x]."');";
           $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_add_usrcats);    
        }
        echo "success";
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['categories'])){ //if nothing is selected delete all
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_del_usrcats);
    }
    unset($usr_cats);
    unset($cats);
}
?>
```

I am not sure what is causing to do that. Something is causing not to update the form after the submission. However, as i said everything works great meaning after i submit the values are stored and saved in the DB, but not shown/updated on the form. Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Thank you

Comment: You are doing your `DELETE`/`INSERT` queries after your `SELECT` queries.  Move those queries before the `SELECT`s. Note, you will need to move the `DELETE` query inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` so you don't delete before form submit.

Comment: actually that was not the issue, I had to insert a header on submit.

Comment: @comsci_dude your procedural logic is still screwed up.

Comment: your `header()` is just fixing your reverse logic. In essence it is doing the same as moving your `DELETE`/`INSERT` before your `SELECT`. Now you are doing a `SELECT`, then `DELETE`/`INSERT`, then a `header()` redirect, and then a `SELECT` again. So you are doing the same thing, but could have been easily fixed by putting your steps in proper order.

Comment: @Sean im working on your suggestion now!! thank you and will let you know :)

Comment: @Sean Thank you, you and Tim cleared this one for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedural logic is backwards and you're doing a bunch of INSERT queries you don't need. As @sean said, change the order.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['categories'])){
        $cats= $_POST['categories'];

        // don't do an INSERT for each category, build the values and do only one INSERT query with multiple values

        $values = '';
        for($x = 0; $x < count($cats); $x++) {
            // add each value...
            $values .= "('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$cats[$x]."'),";

        }
        // trim the trailing apostrophe and add the values to the query
        $qry_add_usrcats="INSERT INTO `user_categories` (`user_id_fk`, `category_id_fk`) VALUES ". rtrim($values,',');
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_add_usrcats); 
        echo "success";
    }
    elseif(!isset($_POST['categories'])){ //if nothing is selected delete all
        // you may want to put this query first, so if something is checked you delete all, so the db is clean and ready for the new data.
        // and if nothing is checked, you're still deleting....
        $qry_del_usrcats="DELETE FROM user_categories WHERE user_id_fk='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';"; //delete all query
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_del_usrcats);
    }
    unset($usr_cats);
    unset($cats);
}
?>

<form action="myprofile.php" method="post">
<?php $usr_cats=array();
$qry_usrcat="SELECT category_id_fk FROM user_categories WHERE user_id_fk='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_usrcat);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $usr_cats[] = $row[0]; // getting user categories from db stored in array
}

$query_allcats="SELECT category_id,category_name, portal_name FROM categories INNER JOIN portals on categories.portal_id=portals.portal_id ORDER BY category_id;";  // select all category queries
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query_allcats);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['portal_name'] . "<input "; //print categories
    if(in_array($row['category_id'], $usr_cats)){ // if in array from db, check the checkbox
        echo "checked ";
     }
    echo "type='checkbox' name='categories[]' value='";
    echo $row['category_id']."'> ". $row['category_name']."</br>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Now I understand what i did wrong, thank you for clearing this up for me.  However I have modified the code a little bit, because as you said that would work only on insertion of new values but not if someones unchecks a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this occurs due to the order of your queries within the script.

If you want to show your updated results after submission, you should make your `update` or `insert` queries to be conditional, and have the script call itself.   The order of your scripts is fine, but you just need to do the following:

Take this query:

```
$qry_del_usrcats="DELETE FROM user_categories
            WHERE user_id_fk='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';"
```

and put it inside the `if` statement so it looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'] {

  $qry_del_usrcats="DELETE FROM user_categories
                    WHERE user_id_fk='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';"
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry_del_usrcats); 

[along with the other updates you have]
}
```

Also, you will need to move this entire conditional above the form itself;  typically any updates, inserts, or deletes should appear year the top of the form, and then call the selects afterward (outside of the conditional)